# Django decorator - Re-enter password to continue

Tags: python, django, decorator

I'm trying to create a decorator that redirects the user to a view that accepts the logged-in user's password and then continues to the requested view if the password is entered correctly. The purpose of this is to add a confirmation step on something like a Delete View.

This is what I have so far:

**decorators.py**

```
def confirm_password(view_function):
    @wraps(view_function)
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # some inner function/logic to call ConfirmPassword view??
        # if something:
        #    from .views import ConfirmPassword
        #    return ConfirmPassword.as_view()(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return view_function(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

**views.py**

```
class ConfirmPassword(UpdateView):
    form_class = ConfirmPasswordForm
    template_name = 'myapp/confirm-password.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.request.get_full_path()
```

**forms.py**

```
class ConfirmPasswordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('confirm_password', )

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ConfirmPasswordForm, self).clean()
        confirm_password = cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')
        if not check_password(confirm_password, self.instance.password):
            self.add_error('confirm_password', 'Incorrect password.')
```

How do I structure the above decorator to correctly call the ConfirmPassword view? Thank you!

Edit - I found a project doing something similar:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/15/how-to-create-a-password-confirmation-view.html

Except, whereas the above requests the user to re-enter their password after so much time has expired, I want the user to be prompted to re-enter their password every time for certain resources.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator please see this functionality in django.

Comment: @hd1 I'm trying to create a decorator to be used in addition to the login_required decorator.

Comment: It would appear you're trying to duplicate its functionality. If not, edit your question to say what you need that is not provided.

Comment: @hd1 I don't see how any of these decorators can be applied here because I'm not testing if the user has permission to view the requested page; I want to check that separately using login_required normally. What I'm trying to accomplish is a check for a user that already is authenticated/has permission. Basically, a "please re-enter your password to continue" page.

Comment: login_required will do just that!

Comment: @hd1 won't that just check is_authenticated on the User object which would return True if already logged in? If the user is already authenticated how do I apply this to just ask the user to re-enter their password?

Comment: instead of asking me, why don't you just try it in django's shell?